# HOWTO Prevent Compiler From Optimizing Specific File

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-optimization

[image]

I am seeing a crash occur when building for 'release' but not on 'debug'. Changing the 'Release' optimization flag to 'None' fixes the issue. However, I would still like to benefit from the Optimizations.

Since there is only 1 file giving a problem, I was wondering if you could tell the compiler NOT to optimize certain files?

Comment: I'd suggest debugging the crash and fixing the code in question. There is a good chance something in the code is architected in a way that fools the compiler. Your screenshot looks like Xcode, is your project in Swift?

Comment: Unfortunately almost impossible to debug the Release build. Code is in Objective C. I am trying everything. I may just end up rewriting the file but trying to avoid that

Comment: post the stack trace of the crash, and the file in question?

Comment: I would but it's no use trust me. I want to know if there is a way to set a compiler flag for a specific .m file